# Firestore Database Array Operations

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm having issues reading data from my Firestore database.

I have create a data base named "nba", with one document with id (Unique ID), this document houses 6 arrays - i have given each array a field name of ("card1", "card2" ... all the way to 6)

Each card contains information of multiple data types that basically describe a unique nba player.

Here is the code for how i'm currently fetching or attempting to fetch these cards.

```
 Future<List<GameCard>> fetchGameCardData() async {
// Reference the specific document in the 'nba' collection
DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('nba').doc('UniqueID').get();

// Loop through all the card fields in the document
for (int cardIndex = 0; true; cardIndex++) {
  String cardFieldName = 'card${cardIndex + 1}';
  List<dynamic>? cardData = snapshot[cardFieldName];

  print('cardFieldName: $cardFieldName'); // Print card field name to make sure i'm 
  accessing the right cards 
  print('cardData: $cardData'); // Print card data

  if (cardData != null) {
    GameCard gameCard = GameCard(
      name: cardData[0],
      team: cardData[1],
      position: cardData[2],
      start: cardData[3],
      date: cardData[4],
      opponent: cardData[5],
      odds: cardData[6],
      market: cardData[7],
    );

    gameCardData.add(gameCard);
      } else {
    // If cardData is null, there are no more card fields
    break; // Stop the loop immediately
      }
    }
    return gameCardData;
  }
```

When i run my code in my terminal, I can see that i pull the right data just fine.

```
I/flutter ( 4489): Balance: 500
I/flutter ( 4489): cardFieldName: card1
I/flutter ( 4489): cardData: [Jewell Lloyd, SEA , G, 9:00 PM, Sat, Aug 26, PHO, 24.5, 
Points]
I/flutter ( 4489): cardFieldName: card2
I/flutter ( 4489): cardData: [Diana Taurasi, PHO, G, 9:00 PM, Sat, Aug 26, SEA, 17.5, 
Points]
I/flutter ( 4489): cardFieldName: card3
I/flutter ( 4489): cardData: [Ezi Magbebor, SEA, C, 9:00 PM, Sat, Aug 26, PHO, 13.5, 
Points]
I/flutter ( 4489): cardFieldName: card4
I/flutter ( 4489): cardData: [Sophie Cunningham , PHO, G, 9:00 PM, Sat, Aug 26, SEA, 10, 
Points]
I/flutter ( 4489): cardFieldName: card5
I/flutter ( 4489): cardData: [Gabby Williams , SEA, F, 9:00 PM, Sat, Aug 26, PHO, 9.5, 
Points]
I/flutter ( 4489): cardFieldName: card6
I/flutter ( 4489): cardData: [Brittney Griner , PHO , C, 9:00 PM, Sat, Aug 26, SEA, 17, 
Points]
```

Unfortunately, right after i get the above response i get the following error

```
E/flutter ( 4489): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled 
Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
E/flutter ( 4489): #0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap 
(package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_
document_snapshot.dart:87:7)
E/flutter ( 4489): #1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent 
(package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_
document_snapshot.dart:105:23)
E/flutter ( 4489): #2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get 
(package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_
document_snapshot.dart:121:12)
E/flutter ( 4489): #3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get 
(package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
E/flutter ( 4489): #4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] 
(package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
E/flutter ( 4489): #5      _HomeState.fetchGameCardData 
(package:brew_crew/screens/home/home.dart:37:41)
E/flutter ( 4489): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4489): 
 W/madra.brew_cre( 4489): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V 
(light greylist, linking)
Application finished.
```

I also do not see the data in my flutter app.

Here's my full code if its any help.

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:brew_crew/models/game_card.dart';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../../models/balance_provider.dart';
    import '../../services/drawer.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  // Added a named parameter key to the constructor
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

//Initialize firebaseAuth Instance
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _logoutScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<
      ScaffoldState>();


  // Create List to hold games
  List<GameCard> gameCardData = [];

  Future<List<GameCard>> fetchGameCardData() async {
    // Reference the specific document in the 'nba' collection
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('nba').doc('UniqueID').get();

    // Loop through all the card fields in the document
    for (int cardIndex = 0; true; cardIndex++) {
      String cardFieldName = 'card${cardIndex + 1}';
      List<dynamic>? cardData = snapshot[cardFieldName];

      print('cardFieldName: $cardFieldName'); // Print card field name
      print('cardData: $cardData'); // Print card data

      if (cardData != null) {
        GameCard gameCard = GameCard(
          name: cardData[0],
          team: cardData[1],
          position: cardData[2],
          start: cardData[3],
          date: cardData[4],
          opponent: cardData[5],
          odds: cardData[6],
          market: cardData[7],
        );

        gameCardData.add(gameCard);
      } else {
        // If cardData is null, there are no more card fields
        break; // Stop the loop immediately
      }
    }
    return gameCardData;
  }

  // Fetch User balance Method
  Future<void> getBalance(BuildContext context) async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      String userEmail = user.email ?? '';
      // print (userEmail);

      try {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .where('email', isEqualTo: userEmail)
            .limit(1)
            .get();
        // Check if the query returned any documents
        //if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        // print('Found ${querySnapshot.docs.length} documents.');

        // Iterate through the documents and print their data
        //for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
        //  print('Document ID: ${documentSnapshot.id}');
        //   print('Data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        //  }
        // }

        if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          // print('Document is not empty Hurray!');
          String userDocumentId = querySnapshot.docs.first.id;
          DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(
              userDocumentId).get();

          if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
            // Explicitly cast the data to Map<String, dynamic>
            Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<
                String,
                dynamic>;

            // Access the 'balance' field from the user's document data
            int balance = data['balance'];
            print('Balance: $balance');
            // Access the BalanceProvider instance and update the balance value
            BalanceProvider balanceProvider = Provider.of<BalanceProvider>(
                context, listen: false);
            balanceProvider.updateBalance(balance);
          } else {
            // print('User document not found for the currently logged-in user.');
          }
        } else {
          //   print('User document not found for the currently logged-in user.');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // print('Error fetching user document: $e');
      }
    } else {
      //print('User is not logged in.');
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeData(context);
  }


  Future<void> initializeData(BuildContext context) async {
    await getBalance(context);
    fetchGameCardData();
  }


// Build App
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,

      key: _scaffoldKey,

      // Drawer widget for displaying a side navigation menu
      drawer: MyDrawer(
        scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
        logoutScaffoldKey: _logoutScaffoldKey,
      ),

      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar.medium(
            // IconButton in the leading position to open the drawer
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
            actions: [
              // IconButton in the trailing position
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ],
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                // IconButton for sports category
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.sports_basketball),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.sports_soccer),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.sports_martial_arts),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.sports_football),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2, // Display 2 cards per row
            ),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final gameCard = gameCardData[index]; // Get the data for the current game 
              card
                return GameCardWidget(gameCard: gameCard);
              },
              childCount: gameCardData.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I cannot tell if i'm running into some issues unique to how firebase store information or if this is due to some asycnhronous data fetching issues. I'm bamboozled.

Comment: I have isolated the eroor to this line

List<dynamic>? cardData = snapshot[cardFieldName];
The issue appears to be tied to the c ardFieldName

StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)